# Can OneSignal send notification across app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, push-notification, onesignal

I'm developing android application using cordova and I include one signal notification as a feature in my app.

I have 2 apps, first for customer and second for seller. Both of my app are using difference package name (com.myapp.customer and com.myapp.seller)

I register onesignal and test to push notification. It's work well.

Now I install the apps to mobile and try to send notification from customer app to seller app (both apps install in the same device) but It doesn't work.

My question is is it possible to send notification from customer app to seller app? If so, how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use one signal REST API and from your customer app send a request to their server. [more info](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification)

Here is java code to send push notification:

```
    try {
   String jsonResponse;

   URL url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   con.setUseCaches(false);
   con.setDoOutput(true);
   con.setDoInput(true);

   con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
   con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj");
   con.setRequestMethod("POST");

   String strJsonBody = "{"
                      +   "\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\","
                      +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                      +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
                      +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"}"
                      + "}";


   System.out.println("strJsonBody:\n" + strJsonBody);

   byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
   con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

   OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
   outputStream.write(sendBytes);

   int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
   System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

   if (  httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
      && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   else {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   System.out.println("jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

} catch(Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
}
```

php code:

```
<?PHP
  function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
      "en" => 'English Message'
      );

    $fields = array(
      'app_id' => "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
      'included_segments' => array('All'),
      'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
      'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                           'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
  }

  $response = sendMessage();
  $return["allresponses"] = $response;
  $return = json_encode( $return);

  print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
  print($return);
  print("\n");
?>
```

**Note:** Replace your seller app id and Authorization key in above code!

Comment: thank you! By the way, do you have an example of PHP? i use codeigniter.